# Android studio - 'Open Module Settings'

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change the setting's of project.
I clicked 'Open Module Settings' but nothing happens. 
I also tried 'File-Project Structure' but it doesn't work too.
Is there anyone who knows the reason??

Comment: Which settings are you trying to find?

Comment: I've seen this behavior on my mac too it seems a bug in Android Studio. When you click 'Event Log' in the bottom right corner does it show 'StackOverflow' every time you try and open module settings?